# creating Outgoing E mail server in odoo 10

Tags: xml, email, odoo

I want to create Outgoing e-mail server. There is a way for doing that from odoo ui. But i want to create e-mail server by defining it as a record in xml. I want it to be defined when module is installed.

like creating an action below :

```
<odoo>
<data noupdate="0">


    <!-- Action Record -->

    <record id="my_action_id" model="ir.cron">

       <field name="name">Name of Record</field>

       <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root" />

       <field name="interval_number">1</field>

       <field name="interval_type">days</field>

       <field name="nextcall" eval="(DateTime.now() + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 01:00:00')" />

       <field name="numbercall">-1</field>

       <field eval="False" name="doall" />

       <field eval="'my_module.model_name'" name="model" />

       <field eval="'function_name'" name="function" />

      </record></data></odoo>
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="0">
        <record id="id_outgoing_mail_server" model="ir.mail_server">
            <field name="name">Name of Record</field>
            <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
            <field name="smtp_host">SMTP Host address</field>
            <field name="smtp_port">SMTP port</field>
            <field name="smtp_encryption">ssl/none/starttls</field>
            <field name="smtp_user">SMTP user</field>
            <field name="smtp_pass">smtp_password</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```